# converting xsl param which has String to xml node in order to lopp through various nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a scenario , where I will pass a parameter to XSLT which is in turn an xml element . But it will be sent as a escape charecters (< for < ....)

My requirement is i have various childnodes in it where I have to loop through them and need to transform . Please find the request , parameter.

Request.xml

```
     <retrievePaymentMethodsRequest>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <retrievePaymentMethodsRequestTO>
    <financialAccountID>3</financialAccountID>
           <bankCountryCode>1</bankCountryCode>
           <clientID>12345</clientID>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <device>003</device>
           <excludedLifeIndicator>003</excludedLifeIndicator>

           <financialAccountStatus>3</financialAccountStatus>
           <kindCode>003</kindCode>
           <notEndedIndicator>0</notEndedIndicator>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <requestMode>003</requestMode>
           <stateCode>003</stateCode>
        </retrievePaymentMethodsRequestTO>
     </retrievePaymentMethodsRequest>
```

parameter to xslt:

```
<b xmlns:fs2="somescheama" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fga="anyvalue"> xmlns:fs2="any value" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="any location "&gt;
                          &lt;statusCode&gt;0&lt;/statusCode&gt;
                          &lt;errorMessage&gt;errorMessage&lt;/errorMessage&gt;
                          &lt;paymentMethodTypes&gt;
                            &lt;!-- NULL or any type code  01, 04 , 10 (sample not real) --&gt;
                            &lt;methodTypeCode&gt;01&lt;/methodTypeCode&gt;
                            &lt;!-- Possible values methodTypeDisplayName 
                                CREDIT_CARD,BANK_ACCOUNT,CASH,CHECK,CASH_EQUIVALENT
                             --&gt;
                            &lt;methodTypeDisplayName&gt;CREDIT_CARD&lt;/methodTypeDisplayName&gt;
                            &lt;!-- valid dollar amount --&gt;
                            &lt;maximumAmountPaid&gt;100.00&lt;/maximumAmountPaid&gt;
                          &lt;/paymentMethodTypes&gt;
                          &lt;paymentFormInfo&gt;
                            &lt;!-- NULL or any type code  01, 04 , 10 (sample not real) --&gt;
                            &lt;paymentMethodTypeCode&gt;01&lt;/paymentMethodTypeCode&gt;
                            &lt;!-- sample form id 1004854 , 1004874 , 1004889 , 1004875--&gt;
                            &lt;formId&gt;1004885&lt;/formId&gt;
                            &lt;!-- Not exactly sure just an assumption --&gt;
                            &lt;formLanguageRefId&gt;US&lt;/formLanguageRefId&gt;
                            &lt;!-- forn name : EFT_AUTHORIZATION --&gt;
                            &lt;formName&gt;EFT_AUTHORIZATION&lt;/formName&gt;
                            &lt;roleActivity&gt;
                              &lt;agentActivity&gt;
                                &lt;inOfficeRulesForActivity&gt;
                                  &lt;!-- for Agent : REVIEW_PRINT, ESIGN , UPLOAD 
                                       for customer : CHECKBOX --&gt;
                                  &lt;customerActivity&gt;REVIEW_PRINT&lt;/customerActivity&gt;
                                  &lt;customerRole&gt;PAYOR&lt;/customerRole&gt;
                                &lt;/inOfficeRulesForActivity&gt;
                                &lt;outOfOfficeRulesForActivity&gt;
                                  &lt;customerActivity&gt;CHECKBOX&lt;/customerActivity&gt;
                                  &lt;customerRole&gt;PAYOR&lt;/customerRole&gt;
                                &lt;/outOfOfficeRulesForActivity&gt;
                              &lt;/agentActivity&gt;
                              &lt;commonActivity&gt;
                                &lt;roleCategory&gt;ONLINE&lt;/roleCategory&gt;
                                &lt;roleForActivity&gt;
                                  &lt;customerActivity&gt;ESIGN&lt;/customerActivity&gt;
                                  &lt;customerRole&gt;PAYOR&lt;/customerRole&gt;
                                &lt;/roleForActivity&gt;
                              &lt;/commonActivity&gt;
                            &lt;/roleActivity&gt;
                          &lt;/paymentFormInfo&gt;
                          &lt;financialAccountOwnerActivity&gt;
                            &lt;canChange&gt;true&lt;/canChange&gt;
                            &lt;!-- valid String --&gt;
                            &lt;searchOptions&gt;searchOptions&lt;/searchOptions&gt;
                          &lt;/financialAccountOwnerActivity&gt;
                          &lt;canChooseAgent&gt;true&lt;/canChooseAgent&gt;
                        </b>
```

Question:
Here most of the complex elements are zero or more . I need to loop through all the elements . But if we have parameter as shown above it is difficult .we cannot implement for-each or any other valid xpath evaluation because in parameter we have xs:String . Is there a way looping through each elements (or) any valid xpath evaluation among xsl:param (or)xsl:copy

Any help appreciated

Thanks
Eresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uploading mule code and as well as xslt where I am sending parameter as document

XSLT file

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:ser="http://service.moneytransfermanagement.financials.icp.sf/">
      <soapenv:Body>
            <soapenv:Fault>
                <faultcode>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$xmlObj/node()"/>
                <!-- 
                <xsl:copy-of select="//$xmlObj/errorCode"/>
                 -->
                </faultcode>
                <faultstring>                       

                </faultstring>                              
                <detail>

                </detail>
                </soapenv:Fault>                
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>     
</xsl:template>
```

and mule code :

```
    <mule-xml:xslt-transformer
        xsl-file="xsl/MoneyTransferManagement/ErrorTransformerXMLTest.xsl">
        <mule-xml:context-property key="xmlObj"
            value="#[groovy:serviceResponse.getFirstChild()]" />                        
    </mule-xml:xslt-transformer>
```

**xml-to-dom-transformer  will conver the String to DOM and we can specify the return class
First child will give us the element handle,,and same we are passing to XSL**

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the simplest method is:

- Put the parameter into an XML document; give it a name (say, `param.xml`).
- When invoking the XSLT processor from the command line, pass the name of the parameter file as a string parameter.
- In the XSLT, declare the appropriate parameter (e.g. `<xsl:param name="paramfile" select="'param.xml'"/>`).
- Declare a variable which gets initialized to `document($paramfile)`.

If you're invoking XSLT from some other environment (e.g. via a Java call), there may be mechanisms for passing document nodes or element nodes to the XSLT processor as parameters, but the details are necessarily implementation-specific and (judging by questions on SO) tend to be easy to get wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we cannot use an external file parse as a document with in xslt and use. we use mule esb, all our payloads from mule will be sent to xslt for transformation . If we send any parameters to xslt from mule , even though it is an xml element all the lessthan and greater than symbols are replaced wuth escape charecters , we are getting exactly as cdata to xslt even though we passed xml to it.

Comment: We too tried using java evaluation in mule esb to pass the parameter as Document but no help . we are getting #[document:null].

Comment: It sounds as if you have two XML streams to hand to the XSLT processor.  If you can't make either of them retrievable from a URI (n.b. that's *not* necessarily the same as "from a file"), another approach would be to wrap both of them into a wrapper document and adjust the XSLT accordingly.  Writing an XML parser in XSLT 2.0 (or using an extension function to parse strings as XML) would be a last resort.  Good luck.